# Error regarding blockdev /dev/sdb1 "BLKRRPART: Invalid argument"

Tags: linux, partitioning, lvm, fdisk

I had to extend an LV on an enterprise server that belongs to `sdb1`, I added/allocated the space I needed from the storage array.

I rescanned the ports of SAN and then I wanted to `blockdev --rereadpt /dev/sdb1` before continuing with `lvextend` command and then `resize2fs` command.

But I got:

```
BLKRRPART: Invalid argument
```

My idea is that I have to blockdev the `/dev/sdb` and not the `/dev/sdb1` but I am not sure.

Do you have any idea?

Output info from `fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 21.5 GB, 21474836480 bytes
64 heads, 32 sectors/track, 20480 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 2048 * 512 = 1048576 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x3d4c6a02
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1       20480    20971504   8e  Linux LVM
```

Answer (score 0):

`--rereadpt` command is for rereading partition table. Partitions don’t have partition table, only disks have. So you should run this command:

```
blockdev --rereadpt /dev/sda
```

Comment: Ohh right, sry.

Answer (score 0):

You real problem is not that you need to reread the partition table (although you failed to do it correctly anyway; see the other answer), but before you `lvextend`, you need to:

1. Resize `sdb1`; if you do it with `fdisk /dev/sdb`, it's practically delete and recreate the partition entry with a new end (and only new end; i.e. make sure it has the same start)
2. Update the size of the PV/VG with `pvresize`